# Connect Four code (Java) Column Placement not working

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

What I am trying to do is make a connect four game where the chips drop to the bottom then it becomes the next players turn.

The problem I was having is that I could only fill in the bottom row because every time I would place a chip there I called the placeChip method again which restarted my for loop. I saw this problem and so I made a static ArrayList to hold the values of the amount of items that had been placed for each row. So for example, if the board was 6 rows by 7 columns, the arrayList would look like this:

```
[6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

In my placeChip method I say if the spot entered is not full, place the chip there. However whatever number I enter a ArrayOutOfBoundsException error occurs and in this case (6x7) it says Index 6 out of bounds for length 6. Here is the code I just referenced (error points to the second line in this snippet, presumably the rowInput part because that is the only new part of this line which semi-worked but still ran before):

```
int rowInput = amountOfItemsInEachCol.get(dropCol - 1);

if (!(playingBoard.isFull(rowInput, dropCol - 1))) { // saying if the spot is not occupied, fill it
```

amountOfItemsInEachCol is the ArrayList mentioned above and dropCol is the value imputed by the user for which column they would like to drop in.

Let me know if I didn't give enough information or if I missed out on including anything else.

Comment: Instead of describing your code with English - just post a [reprex].

Comment: There's not enough code here for us to see the problem.  For example, what type of object is `playingBoard`, and what is the code of its `isFull` method?  As @sleepToken said, you really should post a minimal, reproducible example if you want us to have any chance of being able to see what's going wrong.  We should be able to run the code you provide and get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment so:

`amountOfItemsInEachCol.get(dropCol - 1);` probably gets you the value from the ArrayList which is 6. If your column has a length of 6, the indexes are 0-5. You should probably substract one from your rowInput but that's pretty much a guess as there's too little code.